# при переименовании example.htaccess сайт грузится с ошибкой

Tags: kohana, framework, фреймворк

У меня сейчас стоит kohana 3.3.5, apach2.4 и php 5.4.
При изменении наименования файла “example.htaccess” на “.htaccess”, при входе на загрузке сайта, ошибка:
**ERROR 500 the server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request**
Хотя модуль LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so (в httpd.conf) включен.

При использовании Apache 2.2, ошибка меняется:
**Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_substitute_character() inZ:\home\kohana\www\application\bootstrap.php on line64**

Кто-то знает, как этого можно избежать?

P.S.
В в "error.log" написано:
*Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration*

Я понял что это **проблема с upgrading c apache 2.2 до 2.4**.
а может кто-нибудь скинет ссылочку на русском, чем на https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Apache 2.4 изменили систему контроля доступа. Директива `Order` больше не доступна. Вместо старых директив `Allow`/`Deny`/`Order` следует использовать `Require`. Если же по какой-то причине нет возможности поменять содержимое .htaccess, то требуется подключить специальный модуль, поддерживающий старый формат записей - `mod_access_compat`:

```
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
```

Это требуется указывает в httpd.conf. Ну и соответственно не забыть перезапусть Apache после этого.

---

Если вы не сразу ставили 2.4, а обновлялись с 2.2, то настоятельно рекомендую ознакомиться с этим - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html

Описание изменений на русском - [https://codeby.net/programmy-dlja-servera/важные-замечания-при-обновлении-apache-с-2-2-д/](https://codeby.net/programmy-dlja-servera/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-apache-%D1%81-2-2-%D0%B4/)

Описание новых директив ограничения доступа - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html (в частности см. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require)

Описание модуля mod_access_compat: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html

Comment: **Спасибо**. У меня есть возможность поменять .htaccess. (я ставил Endels 1.72 и в нем находится и Apache 2.2 и Apache 2.4) на сколько я вас правильно понял и предоставленную вами статью, мне в ".htaccess" нужно заменить "* <Files .*> Order Deny,Allow Deny From All </Files>* " на "** <Files .*> Require all granted </Files>** " **И все заработало**

Comment: @Konstantin78 - почти так, только если у вас было `Order Deny,Allow Deny From All`, то в новой версии этому соответствует строка `Require all denied` :) . А `Require all granted` - это наоборот разрешение всем.